# Best way to return logged in user's username in a .NET 3.5 webapp?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sharepoint

Business Intelligence guy here jumping into SharePoint Web Part development after a long, long time off.

I need to return identity of the logged in user ala "Domain\UserName" inside the web part I've completed. I see

```
SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName()
```

But it appears this sucker returns the Full Name of the user - "John Q. Public".

What namespace / method is best to use in a 3.5-based web part to return Domain\UserName, or even better, just UserName?

Thanks!

Comment: I always use System.Environment.Username or System.Environment.UserDomainName

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` works in asp.net.

Comment: make sure to strip out the domain from that as well though.

Comment: Now I am not sure this is the correct answer. Looks like it returns the app pool account. Not what the question is looking for.

Comment: You need to have windows authentication on, otherwise it will return the app pool account